# Add a values to a table from text field

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table, textfield

There is a text field and a table. If we put a value in that text field the corresponding name needs to be displayed on the table from data base:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<center><table>
<tr><td>no</td><td><input type="text" name="no"  autofocus></td></tr>
</table></center>
<br>
<br>
<center>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="60%" border='1' bgcolor="#999999">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th> Element_Number</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['no']))
{
    $c=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("test");
    if(!$c)
    {
        echo "db prob".mysql_error();
    }

    $no=$_POST['no'];
    $qry=mysql_query("select name from opt where no='$no'");
    if(!$qry)
    {
        echo "ret".mysql_error();
    }


        if(mysql_num_rows($qry)!=0)
        {
            $row=mysql_fetch_array($qry);
            $name=$row['name'];
        }
        else
        {
            echo "query Invalid";
        }
    echo    "<td>" .$name."</td></tr>" ;

}
?>
```

when I tried this code output like this-->

```
no--001

|element no     |

|   aaa         |


no--002

|element no     |

|   bbb         |
```

what I want to do to get an output like this--->

```
no--001


|element no     |

|   aaa         |

no--002


|element no     |

|   aaa         |

|   bbb         |


 no--003

|element no     |

|   aaa         |

|   bbb         |

|   ccc         |
```

Comment: You need a while query to get all result and not just the first one

Comment: `"<tr><td>" .$name."</td></tr>" ;`